# When a question says "PQRS is a parallelogram" in what manner should I put the letters?

Tags: geometry

I am doing a vector problem in my textbook to practice, so putting the letters is quite important as I am given the coordinates of P, Q and R but not S and "using vectors" I am supposed to find S. To find S I need to know which letters go where.

So, what is the mathematical convention of placing the letters in for this? Do I go clockwise, anti clockwise? Zig-zag?

Thanks!

Edit 1: I wasn't given an image to work with, but based on the answers so far, would it look like the image below? I am not allowed to embed images, please click the link :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSFED.png

Comment: Note that there is no fundamental difference between clockwise and counterclockwise if you're just doing vector space operations. I would expect the convention to be that the adjacent letters in PQRS are adjacent in the image, i.e. they go cw or ccw, but not any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the order of letters is going clockwise, but there might be some exceptions, although there is no way the picture going zig-zag.

Answer (score 0):

We usually write $\overrightarrow{B}-\overrightarrow{A}$ as $\overrightarrow{AB}$. If you want to type it in LaTeX or MathJax, use `overrightarrow{AB}=\overrightarrow{B}-\overrightarrow{A}`. Your parallelogram example will use either clockwise or anti-clockwise vertex placement, so $\overrightarrow{PQ},\,\overrightarrow{QR},\,\overrightarrow{RS},\,\overrightarrow{SP}$ are vectors each along one side. In particular $$\overrightarrow{S}=\overrightarrow{R}+\overrightarrow{RS}=\overrightarrow{R}-\overrightarrow{PQ}=\cdots$$